# Clone an ArrayList to another ArrayList does not work in DP

Tags: java, arraylist, dynamic-programming

Here is the Java code to find the shortest concatenation of elements of Array `wordBank` to construct String `Terget`, using Dynamic Programming.

**Example:**

**Input:** wordBank = {"ab", "c", "d", "abc", "ad"},
Target = "abcd".

**Output:** {"abc", "d"}.

To do this, I have stored the combination of elements as an ArrayList in a HashMap.
However, the hashMap does not store the values correctly, i.e., the values change when I recursively call the function, although I have cloned the ArrayList before adding it to the map.

Any idea why this happens?

The code works well with arrays.

```
static ArrayList<String> bestConstruct(String target, String[] wordBank, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map) {
    
    if(target.isEmpty())
    {
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    
    if(map.containsKey(target))
        return map.get(target);
    
    ArrayList<String> shortestCombination = null;
    for (String word : wordBank) {
        
        if(target.startsWith(word)) {
            String newTarget = target.substring(word.length(), target.length());
            
            ArrayList<String> combination = bestConstruct(newTarget, wordBank, map);
            
            
            if(combination != null) {
                combination.add(word);
                
                if(shortestCombination == null || combination.size() < shortestCombination.size())
                    shortestCombination = (ArrayList<String>)(combination.clone());
            }
        }
    }
    map.put(target,  (ArrayList<String>) (shortestCombination.clone()));
    return shortestCombination;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to use `clone()` for an arraylist. Use the copy constructor: `new ArrayList<>(combination)`.

Comment: I did the same but still it doesn’t work

Comment: "the values change when I recursively call the function" can you show an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the interaction between these lines:

```
    if(map.containsKey(target))
        return map.get(target);
```

and

```
            ArrayList<String> combination = bestConstruct(newTarget, wordBank, map);
            
            
            if(combination != null) {
                combination.add(word);
```

If you return the memoized list, you're updating it before you clone it.

In general, don't rely on callers to "do the right thing": if you don't want the list in the map to be updated, do the copy yourself before you return it:

```
    if(map.containsKey(target))
        return new ArrayList<>(map.get(target));
```

You may also need to handle the case of a string not being able to be constructed from the word bank.

Comment: what did you mean by "don't rely on callers to do the right thing?" Do you mean because they pass the references?

Comment: @Elahe I mean, if you want to make sure a caller doesn't make changes to the lists stored in the map, don't give them the list stored in the map. Remove their choice to do the wrong thing.